# Does the propery of the object is stored in its prototype?

Tags: javascript

The MDN docs says https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Inheriting_properties

> **When trying to access a property of an object, the property will not
>   only be sought on the object but on the prototype of the object**, the
>   prototype of the prototype, and so on until either a property with a
>   matching name is found or the end of the prototype chain is reached.

Does this mean when a property is added to the object it is added to its prototype ?

ie. In the following code

```
a = {};
a.foo = "hello";
```

is actually stored as

```
a.prototype.foo = "hello"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you store the property on the object then you store it on the object.

It says that when you try to access it (i.e. read it, not write it) then, if it isn't found on the object, it will look up the prototype chain for it.

```js
const a = {};
const b = Object.create(a);

a.foo = "Foo";

console.log(b.foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

It means that when a property is searched for, if it doesn't exist on the specified object, the *prototype* of the object is searched.

If the property is still not found on that prototype, it looks to see if the prototype, in turn, *has its own prototype* - then that is searched.

This process is repeated until either a result is found, or there are no further prototypes to look for the property in - in which case `undefined` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't even change prototype values using assignments:

```js
const p = Object.create(null);
p.a = "initial value on prototype";

const o = Object.create(p);
console.log(o.a);

o.a = "value set by object";

console.log(o.a);
console.log(p.a);
```

And this:

```
a.prototype.foo = "hello"
```

isn't accessing `a`'s prototype. The correct way is:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(a).foo
```

or less formally

```
a.__proto__.foo
```